# How to combine if left and/or functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: DATASET]

I have an example dataset as above. I have 2 columns, namely the duration column and the category column. What is the formula if I want the category column to contain "YES" for `duration < 4` hours and "NO" for `duration > 4` hours?

Comment: Is the value in A a time that's been formatted as `d" days, "H" hours, "m" minutes"`? Or is it text?

Comment: You can use `=IF(OR(--LEFT(A2)>0,--MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,2)>4),"NO","YES")` but what if the duration is 4 hours exactly?

Comment: this columns format is "time" bro

Comment: If the duration 4 hours exactly i want the output "YES"

Comment: @BihaqiAlRafik - Sorry, I'm really trying to be specific. The value is a time that's been formatted? For example, this formula `=TEXT(2 + 1.5/24, "d"" days, ""H"" hours, ""m"" minutes""")` displays `2 days, 1 hours, 30 minutes`, but its value is `2 + 1.5/24`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula should do it, even if you do not have **Office 365**:

`=IF(VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)*24)+VALUE(MID(A2,FIND(", ",A2)+2,FIND(" hours",A2)-FIND(", ",A2)-2))<=4,"YES","NO")`

It extracts the *days value*, turns it into a number and multiplies it with 24 (hours).
Next, it extracts the *hours value*, turns it into a number and adds it to the days result. Finally, everthing is wrapped into an `IF` statement.

*Notes:*

- The formula can be made more robust, if you substitute the constants (+2) and (-2) by `LEN(", ")`.
- For **Office 365** there are easier solutions available.

Comment: Thanks bro, i have one question, why in the last sentence "no" comes before "yes", if I put value "YES" then "NO" the result is true, i use this "=IF(VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)*24)+VALUE(MID(A2,FIND(", ",A2)+2,FIND(" hours",A2)-FIND(", ",A2)-2))<4,"YES","NO") because i will get "YES" if duration <4 hours

Comment: Must have been a typo, I changed it.

Answer (score 4):

B2 Because the conditions <4 hours, so minute no take.

```
=IF(SUM(TRIM(MID(0&A2,FIND({"d","h"},0&A2)-3,2))*{24,1})<4,"NO","YES")
```

Comment: Some really clever pieces here. I did not know that you could coerce numerical text into values.

Comment: You could even use: `=IF(SUM(MID(", "&A2,FIND({"|",","},"|"&A2)+2,2)*{24,1})>4,"NO","YES")`

Comment: hallo bro, I tried edit one of the rows with "0 days, 18 hours, 36 minutes" but the result is "YES" it should be "NO", BTW the duration column is in the formatted "Time"